# How to install rgl and netmata in R 3.3.1?

Tags: software-installation, r, statistics

I am reading the R Springer book of the [authors](http://portal.uni-freiburg.de/imbi/lehre/lehrbuecher/meta-analysis-with-r). Their 00-installation script yields the following warings

```
# List of R packages
pkgs <- c("mada", "meta", "metafor", "metasens", "mvmeta", "netmeta",
          "rmeta", "ellipse")

# Use your favorite CRAN mirror (argument 'repos')
# See website http://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html for a list of
# CRAN mirrors
install.packages(pkgs,
                 repos="http://cran.at.r-project.org/")
```

Warnings as root and repeated 4 times

```
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages(pkgs, repos = "http://cran.at.r-project.org/") :
  installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages(pkgs, repos = "http://cran.at.r-project.org/") :
  installation of package ‘netmeta’ had non-zero exit status
```

R: 3.3.1
OS: Debian 8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `netmeta` package imports the `rgl` package. To install the [rgl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/index.html) package from source some libraries are required:

> SystemRequirements:   OpenGL, GLU Library, XQuartz (on OSX), zlib
>   (optional), libpng (>=1.2.9, optional), FreeType (optional)

On Debian-based distributions it is easier to install the prebuilt binary package:

```
apt-get install r-cran-rgl
```

Afterwards `install.packages("netmeta")` should work in R.

Comment: How did you find that `netmata` import `rgl`?

Comment: See the CRAN page of the package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/netmeta/index.html